# triangle proof: intersection of $w_\alpha$ and $m_a$ is outside $\Delta ABC$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I try to proove, that the intersection $M$ of $w_\alpha$ (angle bisector) and $m_a$ (perpendicular bisectors of $a$) of any triangle $\Delta ABC$ is always outside $\Delta ABC$, except $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral (the same for the other possibilities)

My thoughts: If $M$ is outside $\Delta ABC$, then $|AM|>|AD|$ for $D$ being the  perpendicular foot of $h_a$.

But I had no idea how to start. A geometric or an analytic proof is both fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $M$ are in the same circle. (See figure 1).

[image]

**Figure 1**

Comment: But then I have to show, that $M$ is on the circle, haven't I?

Comment: @ulead86 yes, I think it is sufficient.

Comment: Is it usefull to say $O=(0,0)$ to get started? (this was my first thought)

Comment: Sorry again: I'm still struggling: I understand that $|AM|>|OM|$ but still have no idea how to start the proof.

Comment: @ulead86 Begin with $\triangle ABC$, the circle, its center $O$ and $ma$. Let $M$ the intersection point of $m_a$ and the circle such that $AM$ intercepts $BC$. $M$ is clearly outside $\triangle ABC$ by construction. Note that $m(\angle ABM)=\frac{1}{2} m(\angle BOM)$ and $m(\angle CAM)=\frac{1}{2} m(\angle COM)$, because $\angle BAM$ and $\angle CAM$ are inscribed angles. So $AM$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$,  $M$ is the intersection point of $w_{\alpha}$ and $m_a$, and $M$ is outside $\triangle ABC$.